# Tengo un problema al querer leer un dato por id=, no me muestra el email que guardo en esa id

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Intento leer un dato por id= el cual es un correo que recibo a través de Firebase, todo funciona bien dentro del auth, lee el dato desde la Database y lo muestra en la WebApp, sin embargo cuando quiero leer el dato a través del id= fuera del auth de Firebase no me muestra ningun valor.

Este es el id= en html

```
<p id="user_para2"></p>
```

Aquí lee el dato sin problemas desde la base de datos y lo muestra en el id=user_para2

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      document.getElementById("user_para1").innerHTML = "Bienvenido Usuario: ";
      document.getElementById("user_para2").innerHTML = email_id;

      //if (email_id != "banco1@gmail.com") { firebase.auth().signOut(); }

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});
```

El problema surge cuando intento leer el email que se guarda en el id=user_para2 fuera del codigo de Firebase.auth... Estoy leyendolo de esta manera y no me muestra el email que tiene guardado en esa id.

```
var email_id = document.getElementById("user_para2").innerHTML;      

console.log("Este email es " + email_id);
```

En la consola como resultado me muestra esto

```
Este email es
```

Este es el código del firebase.auth

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      document.getElementById("user_para1").innerHTML = "Bienvenido Usuario: ";
      document.getElementById("user_para2").innerHTML = email_id;

      //if (email_id != "banco1@gmail.com") { firebase.auth().signOut(); }

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});
```

Cuál puede ser el problema por el que no muestra el dato cuando lo llamo por la id, siendo que si se muestra el correo en la web?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, ojalá puedan ayudarme!

Comment: Este error puede ocurrir porque estés llamando al script que lee el email antes de que firebase escriba el valor. ¿Puedes ampliar algo más la información sobre ambos scripts? ¿Cuándo se llama cada cosa?

Comment: Claro, pensaba que podría ser eso, pero el problema es que el email se ingresa en el id= cuando el usuario ingresa al sistema. Y yo estoy llamando al email que se encuentra en id= antes de ingresar al sistema. Lo que pasa es que si trabajo con el email que está dentro del Firebase.auth, el código html no me reconoce las function() que están dentro del Firebase.auth, es por eso que intento llamar la variable desde afuera y esta la llama antes de que exista. No sé cómo solucionarlo... Está medio enredado jajaja

Comment: Me estoy haciendo un lío y no me termina de quedar clara la explicación del comentario. ¿Quieres acceder al valor fuera de firebase antes de que el usuario ingrese en el sistema?

Comment: No, quiero leer el dato cuando el usuario ingresa al sistema y puedo hacerlo trabajando dentro del código del firebase.auth, pero si trabajo dentro de ese código las variables que genero dentro no me sirven para usarlas en el código html, porque no las reconoce. Es por eso que intento acceder al valor fuera del firebase.auth, pero al hacer esto lo llama antes de que el usuario acceda al sistema y me envía un valor vacío... Cómo podría hacer que el valor se lea cuando el usuario ingrese al sistema sin tener que trabajar dentro del código firebase.auth? Dejare el código del auth arriba. Gracias!

Comment: Podrías crear una función que lea el valor y llamarla desde onAuthStateChanged asegurándote así que el valor va a estar relleno

Comment: Parece que está funcionando, deja ver unos intentos más a ver si se soluciona. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Te aviso cualquier cosa.

Comment: Me alegro de que te funcione. Me imagino que es una cuestión del orden en que se ejecuta cada cosa y si la autenticación es asíncrona, entonces vas a necesitar esa función en plan _callback_ que se llamará una vez ejecutada la autenticación.

Comment: Me funciono correctamente por el momento, muchas gracias amigo... Lo último que dijiste no lo entendí mucho jajaja, soy nuevo en esto de la programación, pero voy aprendiendo rápido. Gracias de nuevo.